# Android RecylerView EndlessScroller on load more, jumps to top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using endless scroller with recylerview and it is loading products at bottom but always on load more call my page starts from top not from bottom.

Am I doing something wrong? I am using https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e as an endless scroller and my code in activity is:

```
recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                String load_more_url = url + "&page=" + String.valueOf(current_page);

                bottamProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                productVolleyLoader = new ProductVolleyLoader(getApplicationContext(), load_more_url,productList,
                                          myAdapter,bottamProgressBar, productRecyclerView);
                productVolleyLoader.volleyLoader();
            }
        });
```

Comment: It loads the other items on the end of the list but the screen goes up or it loads the other items on the top of the list?

Comment: @GeorgeR it loads the products at the end and screen goes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very Sorry for this silly question. Actually I was setting adapter in volley loader instead of there I have to set adapter in `onCreate` method and in volley loader I just have to use `notifyDataSetChanged();`.

After that scrolling is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the "onLoad" method, call:

```
    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(lastPosition);
```

Getting the last position from the view with `mRecyclerView.getChildCount()` or something like that if each item is a child inside the RecyclerView. Save it to a variable on the begining, so you'll have the last position before the load and scroll there on the end of the load.

Comment: I tried but nothing happend and my recylerview is a simple list view only. Before I was using ListView only and in that case scrolling was working fine but not in recyclerview.

Comment: @Spartan try to set `stackFromEnd=true` or `setReverseLayout=true` on your Recycler View and see what happens. If it work i'll edit my answer.

Comment: No both are not working and their purpose is different how they can work.

Comment: George I got my mistake, you can see my answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Spartan You're welcome, no problem. Good luck with your app :)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the new values in the old list in load more. So every time its a new list. 
You will have to programmatically scroll to the last position of the view. 
When you are calling for load more, save the position and when list loads, scroll to that position programmatically.